# How to log to a file from contenct script (Fennec extension)

Tags: firefox-addon, fennec

I am able to log to a file from the overlay: I have a console listener that write all logStringMessage to a file. But I cannot get this to work for content scripts injected in pages.

I have verified that all debug messages are logged to the console.

How can I redirect logStringMessage to a file from the content script inside Fennec extensions?

Comment: Current Fennec (up to version 10) is a strange beast. The console lives in the chrome process, not the content process. The error messages from the content process are forwarded to the console in the chrome process. So I guess that console logging should always happen in the chrome process, maybe that's the problem in your case?